# template non-type template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, non-type

I'm trying to use a non-type template parameter which type is a template instance like this:

```
template<size_t num> class BitValue { ... };
class Foo {
  // works
  template<template<size_t> class BitValue, size_t num>
  bool get(BitValue<num> && t) { ... }

  // fails
  template<typename T> bool
  template<Bitvalue<num> bit> bool get() { ... };
  template<template <size_t> Bitvalue bit> bool get() { ... };
  template<template <size_t> class Bitvalue bit> bool get() { ... };
  template<template <size_t> BitValue, size_t num, Bitvalue<num> bit> bool get() { ... };
};
```

You might say: Why not use the `foo.get(value)`? Foo represents a kind of bitfield that has multi-bit values and single-big values. I want foo.get<...>() for all members of the bitfield for consistency.

Why not use `foo.get<typeof(value)>'?
foo.get<MultiBitType>() returns the value of the multi-bit field. foo.get<SingleBitType>() returns the raw value of the single-bit type. But unfortunately some of the bits are negated. So foo.get<NegatedValue>() should return !foo.get<typeof(NegatedValue)>().

Any ideas if it is possible to have a template non-type template parameter at all? And if so how?

Comment: It is not clear what you saying -- you need overloaded `get()` where `get<X>()` return X bits while `get()`  returns exactly one bit?

Comment: you neither can infer the type of non-type template argument, nor you can use an instance of a custom class as a non-type template argument. did you mean [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4fcbfcb0be3ba07) ?

Comment: @myaut I want to overload get() so get<value>() is valid and not just get<Type>() where the type of value is a template class.

Comment: @PiotrS. No. You are using a type. It's not just the bit position `num` that is important but get() also needs the value of `BitValue<num> value`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow that's why I explained that it's not possible what you want

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to have a non-type template parameter of type `BitValue<size_t>` since the allowed types are [temp.param]:

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> (4.1) — integral or enumeration type,
>   (4.2) — pointer to object or pointer to function,
>   (4.3) — lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
>   (4.4) — pointer to member,
>   (4.5) — `std::nullptr_t`.

But you can just template on any type and delegate to a metafunction:

```
template <typename T>
bool get() {
    size_t bit = bit_number<T>::value;
    ...
}
```

where:

```
template <typename T> struct bit_number;
template <size_t N>
struct bit_number<BitValue<N>> : std::integral_constant<size_t, N> { };
// other specializations
```

Comment: PiotrS already suggested that in the comments but that uses the type and not the value. I already have it working for types. I get that I can't use a non-type of BitValue<size_t> but what about making it BitValue<size_t>* or BitValue<size_t>&? That should fit 4.2 and 4.3. What's the syntax for that?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow The syntax would be `template <size_t N, BitField<N>* bf> bool get() { .. }`, but then `bf` would have to have linkage. And you'd have to pass `N` in anyway - so it's a more restrictive, less usable solution than the one you started with.