# Non-Type Template Parameters or Template Parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Good day. I am continuing to read the book " *C++17 in detail* " of *Bartlomiej Filipek*.

Page 63 ( 85 of pdf ebook), he wrote the following code at the bottom of my message.

I kindly ask your help to understand how it works : I have compiled this piece of code , lonely, and it compiled. So, I try to understand why.

I explain the deep motivation of my question :
Usually, I see `struct` templates, `class` templates, function templates. But here , I don't see any of those cases. It seems to be a variable "template", which I am not used to encounter.

I have seen two links that did not reply to my question :

[Non-type template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687540/non-type-template-parameters)

[template non-type template parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559613/template-non-type-template-parameter).

Thank you in advance for your kind explanations about that.

```
template<typename Type, Type value>
constexpr Type TConstant=value;
```

Comment: It is indeed a variable template.

Comment: Thank you Vlad from Moscow. I did not know  that variable template exist.